# How to get Object of calling Activity in an Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two `Activities`.

I got my `FirstActivity` and `SecondActivity` and I start an `Intent` from the first activity which brings me from the first to the second one like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
```

Now I need an `Instance` of my `FirstActivity` in the second activity. My working approach was a static instance in my `FirstActivity`:

```
private static FirstActivity firstActivity;

onCreate(...) { firstActivity = this; }

public static FirstActivity get() { return firstActivity; }
```

This although is breaking `InstantRun` and is considered as a memory leak. I know that I can send `Parcelable`'s through intents, but I need my `FirstActivity` object.

Comment: "Now I need an Instance of my FirstActivity in the second activity" -- why do you think that? I guarantee you that there are better solutions for whatever problem it is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: @CommonsWare I thought that too, but I have the same `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` methods in both activities, so I don't want to write code twice, but just say `firstActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu()` in the second activity in the function.

Comment: Why do you need that instance? Cause you can't!

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin It worked with the static field. See my other comment.

Comment: Using a static object is the worst thing that you can do!

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin That's why I changed it (asked for helped).

Comment: "It worked with the static field" -- that will depend significantly on the version of Android that you are running. Do not assume that having Object A calling some method on Object B will cause Object A to somehow be affected properly, particularly when you are relying heavily on inherited behaviors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical solution for this is inheritance:

Step #1: Create a `BaseActivity` class that extends from whatever you are using right now (`Activity`, `AppCompatActivity`, etc.)

Step #2: Have `FirstActivity` extend `BaseActivity`

Step #3: Move the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` methods from `FirstActivity` to `BaseActivity`

Step #4: Have `SecondActivity` also extend `BaseActivity`

Another option would be to use static utility methods for the common code bits, where those static methods are called by the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` of `FirstActivity` and `SecondActivity`.

Comment: Thanks man. I usually would have come to that conclusion myself, but you really helped me out here!

Answer (score -1):

```js
    //first activity

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("TAG", object);
        
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class).putExtras(bundle);}
                startActivity(intent);
                
//second activity

onCreate().....
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null){
            
            Object object = (Object) bundle.get("TAG");

//and implements serializable in your class object
```

Comment: I don't want to parse a `Serializable` though. @CommonsWare's solution helped me.